# Two apps have to bind to the same port

Tags: tcp

I have two apps that use the same tcp port (and same interface) for the monitoring console, not the main port of application. I am not interested in use that port, and I cannot change the source code for SO_REUSEADDR or for changing the port.

How can I have both applications running on the same OS?

Comment: This is simply not possible since the very purpose of a port is to distinguish between applications.

Comment: @countermode OP is not interested in using the *same* ports. He is asking how to get both programs running. How to change listening ports or IPs or disabling listening at all even though there is no such option in the program itself.

Comment: @rudimeier yes, yes, I got this. Yet, without any way to configure or to patch the programs under consideration the task needs quite some stunt to be pulled of, for _Two apps have to bind to the same port_ is conflicting the very purpose of ports.

Comment: @countermode I think my answer provides two possible ways already.

Comment: @rudimeier I just looked it up - oh dear! Well, `LD_PRELOAD` black art is some kind of patching, is it not... Notwithstanding, I haven't told anything false. Whether the OP is or is not interested in using the same port, this is the challenge he faces. ~ Cleaner than patching would be possibly using different name spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel permitted this, it would have no way to know which incoming connection should be connected to which app.

You should make the apps bind to different IPs. Most apps can do this (but most apps also permit changing their ports...)

If the apps do not permit this, I would run them on different network stacks (either two different physical machines, or virtual machines, maybe dockers).

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this by myself but for Linux you could setup two different IPs for your NIC and use this `bindhack`:

https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes

http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt

Otherwise it could be possible to change the hardcoded port number in the binary using a hexeditor. Disassembling or run in a debugger may help to find the right place where to change it.